# How can I pick up treasure chests?

Tags: majesty-2

I see them all along my route, but I can't figure out how to pick up the gold inside them. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't pick up the gold directly. Your heroes are the ones who go and loot it. Once they loot it, they'll spend it on gear and potions (and some of it comes as tax as well I think). Thieves and Rangers are the best for this task as they'll do more wandering than the Warrior and are faster.

Answer (score 2):

Your minions will loot them eventually. To speed it up, you can put an explore flag on them or build some Rogues since they're particularly fond of them